# Ruby method like `self` that refers to instance

Tags: ruby, oop

Is there a method in Ruby that refers to the current instance of a class, in the way that `self` refers to the class itself?

Comment: `self` *does* refer to the instance. Do you have a concrete example?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`self` always refers to an instance, but a class is itself an instance of `Class`. In certain contexts `self` will refer to such an instance.

```
class Hello
  # We are inside the body of the class, so `self`
  # refers to the current instance of `Class`
  p self

  def foo
    # We are inside an instance method, so `self`
    # refers to the current instance of `Hello`
    return self
  end

  # This defines a class method, since `self` refers to `Hello`
  def self.bar
    return self
  end
end

h = Hello.new
p h.foo
p Hello.bar
```

Output:

```
Hello
#<Hello:0x7ffa68338190>
Hello
```

Comment: Sorry to nit pick on this one, but that first `p self` actually executes at the time the class definition is parsed. The `h = Hello.new` would actually return the same value as `h.foo`. I mention this just in case the listed output might mislead some new Rubyist.

Comment: why I can not call ```p h.bar```

Answer (score 5):

Within an instance method of a class `self` refers to that instance. To get the class within an instance you can call `self.class`. If you call `self` within a class method, you get the class. Inside a class method you can't access any instance of the class.

Answer (score 3):

The `self` reference is always available, and the object it points to depends on the context.

```
class Example

  self  # refers to the Example class object

  def instance_method
    self  # refers to the receiver of the :instance_method message
  end

end
```

Comment: dont forget class methods

Answer (score 3):

the method `self` refers to the object it belongs to. Class definitions are objects too.

If you use `self` inside class definition it refers to the **object of class definition** (to the class) if you call it inside class method it refers to the class again.

But in the instance method it refers to the object which is an instance of the class.

```
1.9.3p194 :145 >     class A
1.9.3p194 :146?>         puts "%s %s %s"%[self.__id__, self, self.class] #1
1.9.3p194 :147?>         def my_instance_method
1.9.3p194 :148?>             puts "%s %s %s"%[self.__id__, self, self.class] #2
1.9.3p194 :149?>             end
1.9.3p194 :150?>         def self.my_class_method
1.9.3p194 :151?>             puts "%s %s %s"%[self.__id__, self, self.class] #3
1.9.3p194 :152?>         end
1.9.3p194 :153?>      end
85789490 A Class
 => nil 
1.9.3p194 :154 > A.my_class_method #4
85789490 A Class
 => nil 
1.9.3p194 :155 > a=A.new 
 => #<A:0xacb348c> 
1.9.3p194 :156 > a.my_instance_method #5
90544710 #<A:0xacb348c> A
 => nil 
1.9.3p194 :157 >
```

You see puts #1 which executes during class declaration. It shows that `class A` is an object of type Class with id ==85789490. So inside class declaration self refers to the class.

Then when class methods is invoked (#4) `self` inside class method (#2) again refers to that class.

And when an instance method is invoked (#5) it shows that inside it (#3) `self` refers to the object of the class instance which the method is attached to.

**If you need to refer the class inside an instance method use `self.class`**

Answer (score 3):

may be you need :itself method?

```
1.itself   =>  1
'1'.itself => '1'
nil.itself => nil
```

hope this help!

Comment: Awesome. Just what I needed. Any cleaner way of doing something like `(0..12).step(1).map(&:itself)`?