# Does self ALWAYS refer to the current instance in an instance method definition?

Tags: ruby, oop

I understand from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077993/ruby-method-like-self-that-refers-to-instance) that in an instance method, `self` refers to the current instance of the class. Is that true no matter how many layers of methods or loops deep in you are within the instance method definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, yes, though there are some metaprogramming methods that can do some strange things with self - for instance, [Object#instance_eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) allows you to pass a block to be evaluated in the context of another instance. In that case, the self within the block is that of the other instance, like so:

```
class Foo
end

class Bar
  def wacky
    puts self.class #"Bar"
    Foo.new.instance_eval do
      puts self.class #"Foo"
    end
  end
end
```

Without a careful reading, you might be tempted to think that the `self` within the block refers to the Bar instance, but this is not so.

So you see, for most purposes, you can assume self is the self that is bound when entering a method. Although you have the ability to pass blocks around that get a different binding, `self` doesn't get re-bound "by accident" in Ruby. For more interesting reading, you might look at the ruby [Binding](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Binding.html) class' documentation.

Comment: self doesn't refer to anything at interpretation time and at runtime always refer to the current instance.Passing a block to instance_eval set the object as the current instance (I.e. in your example foo is set as the current instance). So not just generally but always

Comment: Yes, that's right - I was trying to come up with an example where reading the code would betray a different assignment to self than would be easily detected. A casual reader might think that everything under the `def wacky` statement would refer to a `Bar` instance, but it's not always true - there are ways to reassign self "within" a method. It's clear to the interpreter that a context shift has happened within the `instance_eval` block, but less clear to the programmer who stumbles on this code later.

Comment: I like the answer (aside from implying that what self refers to is inconsistent) and what I like is trying to help read the code

Answer (score 0):

yes self does always refer to self ie the instance the method/block is invoked upon

Comment: @chris and why don't you think that self still refers to the object the method/block is invoked upon. Any method invocation set's self to the instance and passing a block to instance_eval invokes the method upon the instance of the call. So yes self does always refer to the object the method/block is invoked upon. There's simply multiple ways of how to invoke in the context of a given object